# How to create a list of messages in a message with protobuf in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf structure defined in the following way:

```
    syntax = "proto3";

    message Register {

        string name = 1;
        Access access = 2;
        uint64 deafult_value = 3;
        uint64 value = 4;
        uint64 offset = 5;
        int32 index = 6;
        string description = 7;
        int32 register_size = 8;
        repeated Field fields_list = 9;
    }

    message Field {

        string name = 1;
        string regName = 2;
        Access access = 3;
        int32 offset = 4;
        int32 length = 5;
        string description = 6;
        uint64 value = 7;
    }

    message Access {
        bool read = 1;
        bool write = 2;
    }
```

now I want to create a new Register with a list of fields in python and i've tried the following thing:

```
    proto_reg = DataStructs.Register()
    proto_field = DataStructs.Field()
    proto_reg.name ="test"
    proto_reg.fields_list.extend(proto_field)
```

but im getting an exception:

```
   TypeError: Value must be iterable
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer was that i need to wrap `proto_reg.fields_list.extend(proto_field)` with []
so this change works:

```
proto_reg.fields_list.extend([proto_field])
```